# Disable a button in an Addin

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in

I have an ESRI Addin in built in Visual Studio 2013 using .NET for ArcMap 10.3
I have a custom toolbar with a few buttons. One of the buttons is not ready to be shared with the rest of the group. Can I comment out the line in the Config.esriaddinx file? For example, I want to disable the "Edit" button on my toolbar so I can distribute it without that functionality, but not remove it entirely.

```xml
<ESRI.Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.esri.com/Desktop/AddIns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Awesome Toolbar</Name>
  <AddInID></AddInID>
  <Description>My toolbar draws</Description>
  <Version>66</Version>
  <Author>Matthew<Author>
  <Date>2016-10-12</Date>
  <Targets>
    <Target name="Desktop" version="10.3" />
  </Targets>
  <AddIn language="CLR4.0" library="blabla.dll" namespace="TOOLBAR_version_6">
    <ArcMap>
      <Commands>
        <Button id="Draw" class="btn_Draw" onDemand="false" message="Draw" caption="Draw" tip="Draw" category="My toolbar" image="Images\btn_Draw.bmp" />
        <Button id="Edit" class="btn_Edit" onDemand="false" message="Edit" caption="Edit" tip="Edit" category="My toolbar" image="Images\btn_Edit.png" />
      </Commands>
      <Toolbars>
        <Toolbar id="My toolbar" caption="version 6" showInitially="false">
          <Items>
            <Button refID="esriArcMapUI.File_PageSetup" />
            <Item refID="btn_Draw" />
            <Item refID="btn_Edit" />
          </Items>
        </Toolbar>
      </Toolbars>
    </ArcMap>
  </AddIn>
</ESRI.Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can comment out lines in the Config.esriaddinx file by using an XML comment tag

```
<!-- <Button id="Edit" class="btn_Edit" onDemand="false" message="Edit" caption="Edit" tip="Edit" category="My toolbar" image="Images\btn_Edit.png" /> -->
```

and

```
<!-- <Item refID="btn_Edit" /> -->
```